# How do I get MSFlxGrd control for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

I am migrating to a new computer.  It's running Win7 Pro SP1, same as my old one.  I have installed the VS2008 and VS2012 compilers, same as my old one.  I have an ActiveX control originally developed in VS2008 that I am migrating to VS2012.  It works on the old machine.  On the new one, it throws an assertion failure from deep inside MFC source code.  I have just managed to find the problem:  the MSFlxGrd control is not installed on the new computer.  What is the best way to get it?

Comment: It is a VB6 control, you'd have to install it.  You can still get the installer through an MSDN subscription.